Anyway to hightlight in adobe acrobat without using mouse?
I want to use only my keyboard to highlight text without using my mouse. Press Shift-Right_arrow to select the text and then use some shortcut to highlight the text. Is there any way to set this as a shortcut?
I saw many answers about Shift-U, but that's not what this question is about
